# SQL low disk space alert

Tags: sql

Hi please I just started my first MYSQL DBA project but I need a help please I have a database of just 100MB but I want to send alert through the operators mail if the space left is less than 20MB

Comment: What have you tried, what's not working?

Comment: This is an administration question, not a programming one. Should be closed.

Comment: The disk is typically managed by the OS, not the DBMS directly. For this task, means of the OS are the prime suspects. Therefore it would also help to know which OS you're using. And I opt for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).